# How can I set goals in embedded field?

Tags: software-industry, productivity

I have 2.6 years of experience in my current company as an embedded software developer. But still have not any aim or goal in future life. How is money after 40's for people with experience in embedded field ?
I am now dealing with both software and hardware.

Comment: Unrelated, but please tell me "2.6" doesn't mean 2 years and 6 months.

Comment: @jcm yes 2 year and 6 month

Comment: Why not just write 2.5 years? ;)

Comment: If you're an engineer: 2Y6M :)

Comment: The correct way to write 2 years 6 months is, of course, 2.6.  Any engineer in any field should/would be completely familiar with different number bases, and different notational systems.  The obvious and natural notation is indeed 2.6.  (Similarly for anyone involved with software "1.5" obviously does not mean "version one and a half".)

Answer (score 6):

Being employed with steady pay increases to keep pace with inflation is a normal ambition. It's not necessary to have aims and goals past that.

Pay in the embedded field is usually quite high, if you don't feel you're making enough where you are, apply for positions elsewhere.